# Electronic Frontier Foundation's Cat Joke

Tags: python, linux, security

I stumbled upon this article: [Electronic Frontier Foundation - Coders' Rights Project.](https://www.eff.org/issues/coders)

I'm trying to understand the code in this image:

[image: cat joke]

Code from the picture:

```
$ open catfood
catfood: Unable to open catfood
Permission denied
$ cat > canopener.py
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('127.0.0.1', 7500))
crash = '\x41'*1337
eip = '\xFF\xFE\xEF\x08'
payload = open("msf-bindshell-8888.bin").read()
sock.send(crash+eip+payload)
sock.close()
$ chmod +x canopener.py; ./canopener.py
$ nc -vv localhost 8888
localhost [127.0.0.1] 8888 (?) open
# open catfood
Opening delicious catfood...
```

My understanding is that this is some kind of a hack to get unauthorized access using python code, connecting to localhost and sending payload but my knowledge stops there.

Is this an actual hack or just a joke I don't understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is entirely based in reality. Breakdown:

- The user wants to run the command `open catfood` but lacks the necessary permissions to do so.
- There is a program running as root on the same computer and listening on `127.0.0.1:7500`.
- Said program contains a buffer overflow vulnerability that can lead to heap execution.
- The user creates a file called `canopener.py` to exploit the vulnerability, by first sending `crash`, 1,337 letter A's (this is what `'\x41'*1337` produces) to overflow the buffer, then `eip`, the address of the code to run (the details to calculate this aren't present here, so we just assume they calculated it right), then `payload`, the payload code itself (`msf-bindshell-8888.bin`, a payload from Metasploit that offers a shell on port 8888).
- The user makes the exploit script `canopener.py` executable and then executes it. This causes the payload to be ran as root.
- The user connects to port 8888, and is presented with a root shell (indicated by the `#` prompt instead of the past `$` prompt).
- The user uses their new root shell to run the `open catfood` command.

Comment: Thank you. How do we know point 2? Is there always a program like that? And how could I defend myself from this?

Comment: The program in the picture is a contrived example and wouldn't be installed on real computers. To defend yourself against real programs with similar vulnerabilities, the best thing you can do is to stay on top of updates for all programs on your system.